# Using template in Chrome Extension popup html: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, underscore.js, content-script

In chrome extension popup html (page that is shown when you click on chrome extension icon) I am trying to render a template. I added underscore library and I've written a small template.

```
var html = _.template("<p>Blah Blah Blah</p>");

$("body").append(html);
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

I'm trying to find a way of using templates in popup pages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807437/underscore-js-template-causes-error-from-chrome-extension might be related

Comment: Can you precompile the template rather than calling `_.template` at run-time?