# How to inject javascript into DOM of a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, code-injection

I am developing a chrome App that would serve as an Arduino code editor based on [Cylon project](https://cylonjs.com/). A js script (let's call it `output.js`) is generated incorporating the led toggling logic or whatever else we want to achieve with the arduino and compiling it with other node dependencies using browserify. In their [chrome extension example](https://github.com/hybridgroup/cylon-example-chrome) they statically reference this script in `index.html`.

Since, I am working on an editor that will allow users to write arbitrary code to work on arduino, I am generating the contents for `output.js` dynamically. I have gotten to a point where I can successfully generate contents of `output.js` and I have written a function that injects that data into a `script` tag. However, Google Chrome throws an error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Mugizlz7AFKJ2hm6UA9ySY/31cKCVhLaEX9/QYpJIsk='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. 
Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So, I realize I need to execute inline javascript which could be a potential security vulnerability. I know that [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are designed specifically to inject custom JS or CSS into web pages but they work in context of a website or web address.

I want to modify the dom and inject custom JS in a standalone chrome App and not a chrome extension that works in context of some websites or tabs. From whatever little research I did on the subject, I guess content scripts are not a valid concept for chrome apps. How do I then inject javascript into the DOM for a chrome App. What are the possible alternatives to content scripts I have in this situation?

Comment: Chrome apps may declare a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox).

Comment: You can try the [solution in this github forum](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2579) where the dev created a function that accepts the URL of the JS file to be executed. Check this [code samples](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399) for more code reference.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to make a `manifest.json` file, that includes the hash in the error message.

For instance, your `manifest.json` may look like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "arduino editor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "46",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-Mugizlz7AFKJ2hm6UA9ySY/31cKCVhLaEX9/QYpJIsk='",
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  }
}
```

See the following post for more in-depth info.

[Chrome Extension - Content Security Policy - executing inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625412/chrome-extension-content-security-policy-executing-inline-code/38555325#38555325)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jeff. I have a similar `manifest.json`, but the contents of `output.js` can dynamically change so I can not hardcode a `sha256` signature in Manifest as it would be invalid as soon as the script is modified.

Comment: Can you recalculate the `sha256` in your build system?

Comment: Even if I can Jeff, I will have to update the `manifest` with the new signature. I don't think that is a feasible option for a chrome app during run time.