# Is there a way to allow unsafe-inline code in a chrome extension (MV3)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, manifest.json

I am currently making a chrome extension (in Manifest Version 3) and I am trying to allow inline event handlers. In my popup.html I want to run a function when a button is clicked, as shown below:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="foo(this)">bar</button>
```

(Separate) JavaScript:

```
function foo(x){
    console.log(x);
}
```

When I run the extension I get the following error:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
> Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I have tried to add a content security policy and a nonce to my JavaScript file (to allow the inline-execution to work) but that has not worked either:

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'nonce-baz'"
},
```

Adding the content security policy causes the following error:

> 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value
> "'nonce-2726c7f26c'" in directive 'script-src'. Could not load
> manifest.

So I am wondering how I can allow the inline-code to be executed. (I have seen this post: [Chrome Extension - Content Security Policy - executing inline code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625412/chrome-extension-content-security-policy-executing-inline-code/38555325#38555325), however, the answer is using Manifest Version 2, while I am using Manifest Version 3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about making a chrome extension but it might help if you use an `.addEventListener`. I have heard that using onclick isn't recommend so you might want to use and `.addEventListener` anyways.

In your case I think it should look like:

html:

```
<button id='putIdHere'>bar</button>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('putIdHere').addEventListener('click', {
   console.log('stuff')
});
```

Not sure if this helps, but hopefully you can do something with it :).