# How to use Firebase CDN in Chrome Extension bypassing CSP restrictions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

### Scenario

I have been trying to use Firebase CDN for my Chrome Extension. When I try to do that, I get an error stating that the CSP is not allowing inline Javascript to execute.

### Error

The CSP has blocked inline Javascript, stating that XSS is possible. While I don't want that to happen, I do want to implement Firebase.

### Work done so far

First, I tried creating a nonce with a meta tag. That didn't work. Then I tried exporting it to another file, but it tells me script-src blocked the Javascript.

*So, what I'm I supposed to do?*

Comment: please let me know which Manifest version you used

Comment: I used manifest v3

Comment: And possibly my question is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502307/chrome-version-18-how-to-allow-inline-scripting-with-a-content-security-policy?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MV3 doesn't support remote hosted code anymore so everything should be bind inside extension package.
Please let me know any questions after reading this.
https://gist.github.com/cheadrian/8424217dda5a28724f290eef7fb4e059